# Cron Expression convert to Spring Format

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron

I found out that Spring uses its own cron expression format. The thing is, I got an app where the user can input some cron expression to schedule a task so I'd like to take that cron expression and use with CronTrigger.

Is there any way to convert a normal cron expression into a Spring format?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [CronSequenceGenerator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) by Spring.

Date sequence generator for a [**Crontab pattern**](https://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/), allowing clients to specify a pattern that the sequence matches.

The pattern is a **list of six single space-separated fields**: representing second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday. Month and weekday names can be given as the first three letters of the English names.

> **Example patterns:**
>
> - "0 0 * * * *" = the top of every hour of every day.
> - "*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds.
> - "0 0 8-10 * * *" = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
> - "0 0 6,19 * * *" = 6:00 AM and 7:00 PM every day.
> - "0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 and 10:30 every day.
> - "0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI" = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
> - "0 0 0 25 12 ?" = every Christmas Day at midnight